# dispatch_async throwing NSPathStore2 error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm calling a function within a category that's throwing the exception error:

```
-[NSPathStore2 countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f5572b0
```

The error is being thrown within this block.

```
NSArray *shindys = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSError *error = nil;
__weak UIManagedDocument *shindyDatabase = self.shindyDatabase;
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Shindy Fethcer", nil);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    for (NSDictionary *shindyInfo in shindys) {
        [Shindy shindyWithShindyDBInfo:shindyInfo inManagedObjectContext:shindyDatabase.managedObjectContext];
        [shindyInfo setValue:self.detailView.text forKey:@"details"];
        NSLog(@"This is getting performed.");
    }
});
```

Pre-allocating the `NSDictionary` didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'shindys' isn't an NSArray. If you stop calling -objectAtIndex:, it will be.

Comment: Yeah but then he'll just get an error when he gets to the `setValue:forKey:` line.

Comment: Ah... Thank you. Rob, you're correct, although, it fixed the error that I was presently dealing with.

Comment: I suppose if anybody stumbles upon this some day and faces that `setValue:forKey:` error, all they need to do is prevent the memory cycle that they created because of `self`.

Comment: The retain cycle between the block and `self` goes away as soon as the block finishes executing.  It's harmless.

Comment: Yeah, but why not do it just in case it becomes harmful in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Under the covers, a `for(element in container)` loop uses the `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` message to enumerate the elements of the container.

The `NSPathStore2` class is a subclass of `NSString` which the system uses for strings that are known to be filesystem paths.

The exception message is telling you that `NSPathStore2` doesn't support the `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` message.

This makes sense because `NSString` (and the `NSPathStore2` subclass) isn't an object container.

The `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` function does return an `NSArray` (which is an object container that you can use in a `for/in` loop), but you are picking out the first element of the array (the `NSPathStore2` instance) using `objectAtIndex:`.  So even though you declare `shindys` as an `NSArray`, you're actually setting it to an `NSPathStore2`.

The way you're calling `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, it will always return a 1-element array, so the idea of picking out its first element using `objectAtIndex:` is fine.  There's no reason to try to enumerate all of its elements, because it will only have one element.

Furthermore, in your block, you're sending `setValue:forKey:` to `shindyInfo`, expecting `shindyInfo` to be a dictionary.  But even if `shindys` were an array, it would be an array of strings, because that's what `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns.  And strings don't have any properties you can set with `setValue:forKey:`.

This code is a mess.  It's not clear what you're trying to do, but I think you don't understand the purpose of `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`.

Comment: I appreciate your overly-explanatory explanation :)